# Single query to delete multiple records WITHOUT InnoDB relation (with JOIN?)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-delete

**Problem:**
I have 2 rather large tables: `message` (+20 million records ~ 11GB) and `message_subject` (14 million records ~ 3GB) that need to be 'cleaned up'.

I need to delete all messages older than 2 weeks along with the corresponding message_subjects if the message has a subject, but it's important to note that **not all messages have a subject** and messages older than 2 weeks without a subject need to be removed too.

These 2 tables do NOT have a relation specified through InnoDB, even though `message_subject` has the field `message_id`.

If a relation was specified between the 2 tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, I could just delete the record from `message` and the corresponding `message_subject` would automatically be removed, however this isn't the case.

**I have tried:**

```
DELETE message, message_subject
FROM message
INNER JOIN faq 
WHERE message.id = message_subject.message_id 
AND message.add_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Which deletes messages that have a subject; messages older than 2 weeks without a subject are not deleted.

```
DELETE message, message_subject
FROM message
INNER JOIN message_subject
      ON message.id = message_subject.message_id 
WHERE message.add_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

does exactly the same as the first query; it doesn't delete the old messages without a subject.

Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Are you looking for an `outer join` instead?

Comment: @sgeddes lemme give that a shoot and see what happens.

Comment: generally being in a position where you have so much data to delete is a pain because you could run into performance issues. For example it could be really slow because you have many delete operations or your redo log may get too big. Consider deleting in batches, i.e. committing every 10K records (you should performance test the threshold to see what works best for you), and I would even suggest that you either start deleting data more frequently or redesign your database to use partitions because they are quick to dispose of.

Comment: @benji right you are, it really is a pain to delete so many records on a production server which can't be slowed down too much, so I will indeed be runnning a cron that does the deleting in batches, that's the reason I want to do it with 1 query.

Comment: @deacs what's the problem with doing it in 2? i.e. first delete all the subjects and then all the messages..

Comment: @sgeddes looks like the outer join worked, do you want to post an answer so I can award you your correct answer?

Comment: @benji if i use 2 queries, i will have to join in the second query anyway (to get subjects without a message), so may as well use a single query with a join to do both at the same time. so not really a problem, just more optimal imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to sgeddes' comment, I was able to solve the problem using the following query:

```
DELETE message, message_subject
FROM message
LEFT OUTER JOIN message_subject
      ON message.id = message_subject.message_id 
WHERE message.add_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Which apparently is the same as

```
DELETE message, message_subject
FROM message
LEFT JOIN message_subject
      ON message.id = message_subject.message_id 
WHERE message.add_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Comment: Feel free to accept this as the answer - although I wonder if creating new tables from the good data wouldnt be faster

Comment: @Strawberry I'll only be able to accept my own answer after 2 days. And I agree, a whole new table would be a faster sollution, that unfortunately isn't an option in my case.